# Keras multilabel text classification

Tags: classification, text-mining, tensorflow, multilabel

As many people, I've been following Andrew NG's course and I'd like now to work on a multilabel (short) text classifier with Keras/TensorFlow/Scikit learn.

I'm new to this and I know this is not exactly the kind of questions that we're supposed to ask here but where can I find a small full example (data + implementation) of a multilabel text classifier that I could run out of the box?

I've been looking all over the internet and couldn't find something like this.
I need a first example to modify, change features etc to fully understand how it should work.

Answer (score 2):

A shameless plug over here. Feel free to check [Magpie](https://github.com/inspirehep/magpie), a framework for multi-label text classification that builds on `word2vec` and neural network technologies. It should run out-of-the-box if you have a good dataset and it builds on the technologies that you mentioned (keras, TF and scikit-learn).

I managed to run it for classifying texts with up to 10k labels with reasonable performance. Thanks to `word2vec` it should also be able to work for an arbitrary language.